# How to correctly use map and use np.where to replace values in a column

Tags: pandas, numpy, mapping, data-cleaning

This is the city column of my dataframe- df.city

```
array(['la', 'hollywood', 'pasadena', 'los angeles', 'new york',
       'studio city', 'venice', 'santa monica', 'mar vista',
       'beverly hills', 'w. hollywood', 'encino', 'st. boyle hts .',
       'westlake village', 'westwood', 'west la', 'chinatown',
       'monterey park', 'rancho park', 'redondo beach', 'long beach',
       'marina del rey', 'culver city', 'burbank', 'century city',
       'malibu', 'seal beach', 'northridge', 'st. hermosa beach'],
      dtype=object)
```

I want the strings containing `['la','hollywood']` to be converted to `'los angeles'`. How to do this, i was using `np.where(condition,x,y)` for this but its third-argument(y) let me down.

To replace the rest of the cities i made this dictionary

`cities={'studio city':'los angeles', 'santa monika':'los angeles', 'mar vista':'los angeles', 'beverly hills':'los angeles', 'encino':'los angeles', 'st. boyle hts .':'los angeles', 'westwood':'los angeles', 'chinatown':'los angeles', 'moterey park':'los angeles', 'rancho park':'los angeles', 'redondo beach':'los angeles', 'century city':'los angeles', 'marina del rey':'los angeles', 'malibu':'los angeles', 'seal beach':'los angeles', 'northridge':'los angeles','st. hermosa beach':'los angeles'}`

When i use `df.city.map(cities)` , it maps the ones present in dictionary and replace the others such as 'los angeles' with NaN's.
How can I go about cleaning this column of my dataframe column?

Comment: Use `df['city'].replace(cities)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `np.where` like this:

```
df['city'] = np.where((df['city'].str.contains('la'))| (df['city'].str.contains('hollywood')), 'los angeles', df['city'])
```

The third argument is just the original column.